# Touch-friendly radio buttons for mobile devices?

Tags: mobile, responsive-webdesign

I am using WordPress and WP Pro-Quiz to create a quiz.

Each answer has a radio button on the side (`input type="radio"`). When I click anywhere on the same row from the touch-screen on my computer, the radio button is being checked.

But when I click on the row on my mobile device (in this case an iPod touch), the radio button is not being checked. I have to click exactly on the tiny radio button to check it.

So I see two possible ways of solving this problem. Either I try to make a large radio button, or I try to make the whole row "mark"-able.

What would be the easiest approach? Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `<label>` tag for the text next to the radio button, it should make that text clickable, even in mobile browsers.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"><label for="male">Male</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female"><label for="female">Female</label><br>
```

Comment: I will try that! I saw that the label was nested like <label><input type="radio"/></label> which doesn't make it work on my IOS testing device.

Comment: This is also really helpful for desktop users, as catching the radio button with a mouse pointer can be difficult too.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons can be fiddly on Apple devices you should opt to use [UI buttons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) instead.

Another issue could be that the z-index on the radio buttons is not set meaning your click the form not the element.

Comment: the OP is a using a premium WP plugin, they may not be able to implement this suggestion.